# How to get total gross revenue for current month in the woocommerce dashboard status widget

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to show gross sales for the current month in woocommerce status widget in admin dashboard. Currently it shows net sales amount I need to change to gross sales amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Ni WooCommerce Dashboard Sales Report](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ni-woocommerce-dashboard-report/) plugin. It enables you to get a quick information about store sales order on WordPress dashboard Its Sales By Month Report feature shows the total gross sales of the last six months.